# Can't use "wscanf" while using "_setmode (_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT)"

Tags: c, windows, mingw

I am trying to implement input and output of Cyrillic characters in my program. I read [this](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8) answer how to implement it (it's on russian). It says that using `_setmode (_fileno (stdin), _O_U16TEXT);` should work fine with UTF-8 characters using `wscanf` or `wcin`.

Here's an example of a small wchar input not using _setmode:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int input = -1;

    wprintf (L"Enter a number: ");
    wscanf  (L"%d", &input);
    wprintf (L"%d", input);

    return 0;
}
```

Which works fine when entering a number: input number is written to the console. But when I try to  use _setmode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main()
{
    int input = -1;

    _setmode(_fileno(stdin),  _O_U16TEXT);

    wprintf (L"Enter a number: ");
    wscanf  (L"%d", &input);
    wprintf (L"%d", input);

    return 0;
}
```

then `wscanf` doesn't do anything - it returns 0, and input variable is not changing, so output to the console is always -1.

I don't understand why this happens. `_fileno (stdin)` returns 0 as it should do for stdin. `_setmode` returns 16384, so it's not -1, which should mean that it works correctly. Also, my source files are encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: What happens if you add `#include <io.h>`?

Comment: @AdrianMole using `#include <io.h>` changes nothing. I'll correct language tag to "C" (oh, you did it, ok), through I'm using C++ Code::Blocks project, probably it includes io.h itself.

Comment: Where does stdin data come from? A pipe? What is the encoding of the input?

Comment: @Anders I'm sorry, how can I view the encoding of the input? I'm not sure if I understand what pipe input is, but I think I don't use it, I just enter data from a keyboard to the console.

Comment: If you are typing with the keyboard then the input is not redirected (not a pipe nor file). This is important to know to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> *"should work fine with UTF-8 characters using wscanf or wcin"*

(typo?) Windows doesn't support UTF-8 input (at least not in Windows 10 and earlier, only UTF8 output is supported) `_setmode` does enable UTF-16 input.

The IDE may use its own console which is not compatible with wide char. Make sure you run command prompt from windows, and execute the program within Windows command prompt.

Use `ReadConsoleW` API to see if Unicode is supported, or use this API directly instead of `wscanf`

Enable Unicode for both input and output

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```

Comment: These functions are in the C runtime so not strictly tied to a Windows version. Related: https://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/

Comment: 1. Yes, a typo, but in code: I'm trying to enable UTF-8 input, but I shall use _O_U8TEXT. 2. I tried to compile the same code in Dev-C++ using MinGW, I tried to compile it myself using MinGW - doesn't change anything. 3. Uuuh let me check that. 4. Using both those lines doesn't change anything. **So, it works fine with _O_U8TEXT**, but I still wounder what I misunderstand the use of UTF-16.

Comment: @Anders I am not sure what you mean. The link you posted shows that UTF8 input doesn't work in Windows. If you scroll down to page 50, you see usage of `ReadConsole`, `MultiByteToWideChar`, and deprecated `codecvt`. But if UTF8 works fine then I am happy for everybody. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani But I noticed that using _O_U8TEXT with both stdin and stdout makes another problem: it doesn't let me output Cyrillic characters with `wprintf (L"...")`. Using _O_U16TEXT for stdout and _O_U8TEXT for stdin solves the problem, but I'm sure it's a wrong use of encoding. Thus: _O_U8TEXT for both streams don't work with constant L-string, _O_U16TEXT doesn't work with stdio input. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There seems to be two problems. First, "UTF16 input" doesn't seem to work with MinGW (it does work with Visual Studio, I haven't tried with MinGW). Did you solve this first problem? Second, you have a UTF8 file, you can convert UTF8 to UTF16 using `MultiByteToWideChar`, use `wprintf`. Or you can set `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)/printf`